# File(.txt) Input Output from .trace file of XCODE UI Automation

Tags: javascript, xcode, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to write debug lines from my automation script(.trace file) to a text file on local file system. I am using XCode Automation Instrument.

Can anybody guide me on how this is done?

Comment: you want to write a script in some text file and debug it in instrument ?? right ? or can you elaborate the question ?

Comment: I am writing the JS in the UI automation's Script screen and running the Automation. But I need to provide the results of the Automation in a plane text file.At present, I am extracting fields from from the application and displaying it in the "Log Message" Section of the editor log. But I need to make this more readable to  help QA pinpoint the failures. Logging that happens in Editor log is not readable and also it cannot be sent to a Developer to show the steps. Hence I am working on logging debug lines to a Text File.

Comment: Please throw some light on a good methodology to  accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present , you can not get the txt file . You will either get plist file and manually you have to write it into txt file or you can also get result in terminal window , if you wish you can write it into txt file , but that will be one by one .. you can not write all the result at a single go .

/// Get the Results from Instruments.

These are the steps to get the result on Instruments:-

```
1) In a application go to profile and open the Instruments .

2) Click on Library there and find the Activity Monitor tool .

3) Press the start button . and find out the process name (mostly you have to find out the name of your application there )

4) Now see if there any leaks you will get that red graph there , As I told you yesterday .

5) Now if there is any leaks and you can see the leaks in Instruments then go to ---------> Terminal 

6) check your process name and write the command there :-  leaks yourprocessname

7) you will get the generated leaks report here .
```

Comment: Thank you Jean. 
I will work on getting the status on terminal.

Comment: @Shreyas, See above edited answer to know how to get results from Instruments .

Comment: Hello Jean, Your advice was helpful. Thank you for this valuable Input. Now I am able to write debugs to files.

Comment: I am glad it helped you ... but tell me one thing are you writing it into text file one by one manually?

Comment: No, I just redirected the Output which comes to Terminal to a TXT file.  Do you have any other suggestions to this?

Comment: No I just thought . if you know objective C then you can get the plist file and by reading all the data in plist files and those data you can write in any txt file . The point here is you don't have to do it one by one . First get the result in plist then write the program that gathers all the plist and get the data and writes that data to txt or excel in one go